# How to determine the maximal, minimal, greatest, and smallest elements for the subset relation $\subset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

If I have a set $S=\{\{a, b\}:a, b\in X\}$ and consider the subset relation $\subset$, how can I determine the maximal, minimal, greatest, and smallest elements? Wouldn't all the possible elements inside $S$ be maximal/minimal since they are the same size?

Comment: you are very nearly right, but there's one additional case you need to consider! hint: what if $a=b$?

Comment: Ah right, so if $a = b$, then the single element would the greatest and smallest. Is this correct?

Comment: You have to be careful what a/the maximal/greatest elements are? Note that the inclusion is not a linear ordering, i.e. there exists set which you cannot compare (if $|X|>2$)

Comment: You are not looking for the greatest element etc. within $\{a,b\}$  but for the greatest element in $S$, which is a set of sets.

Comment: Thank you for everyone’s feedback! So since all the internal sets within $S$ are the same size (by its own definition), then they would all be maximal and minimal, and if $a=b$ then the single element would also be the biggest and smallest. Is this understanding correct?